# Server 2008 Roaming Profiles and Chrome userdata

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, roaming-profile

Firstly, this Server 2008 box has taken over from a server 2003 PDC several months ago and I can't quite say for certain that everything has transitioned correctly. The domain functionality has been raised to 2008 r2 and netdom query shows the 2008 box as controlling everything, however.

Also, many if not all of the profiles have been around since the XP days so the roaming profile folder has both profile and profile.V2 folders and there doesn't seem to be consistency as to which is being used for what, and why. e.g. for Firefox, things are being updated in `profile/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla` and `profile.V2/AppData/` is basically empty save for a MSFT folder with some crypto stuff in it. However, it seems that the majority of other stuff is being updated in `profile.V2/`. Confusing.

My question/problem is that I need to not only have cookies follow users around for firefox (which works as mentioned above), but also now for Chrome. However, Chrome data lives in AppData/Local which doesn't get shared.

It also doesn't look like Folder redirection will do what I need.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

edit: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2423

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/eula.html?msi=true

The msi installer seems to function the way I need.